# Adjusted Rand Index Per Single Cluster

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

i have a nuanced ARI question for which i can't find any reference.
say i have two clusterings, say ClusteringA and ClusteringB, and i am comparing them using ARI. now, i'm not interested in the ARI itself, but in the contribution of each cluster in ClusteringA to the ARI.

A synthetic use-case that may demonstrate the need:
i have medical data. i clustered it using method A and received 3 clusters. lets call it ClusteringA. Showed it to a doctor who said sure - those are cases of Flu, Covid, and healthy people. i trust Method A so i name the clusters Flu, Covid, and Healthy.

now i clustered the same data using method B and received 3 clusters. lets call it ClusteringB. Showed the clusters to the doc who said 'the first cluster is the healthy people, the two others are just a random mix'.

now, if I would run ARI on (ClusteringA,ClusteringB), the cluster of the healthy people (cluster 3 in the ClusteringA) would contribute most of the value.

What i am looking for is a way to measure 'similarity' PER CLUSTER.
Namely, a formula for computing the ARI for each cluster within the baseline clustering.
Hopefully, with an implementation in python or R.

thanks!